# Volvo S80 Ventilator odor

Tags: volvo, s80

I have a 2008 Volvo S80 and there is a terrible odor coming from the vents but NOT when the A/C or heat is on. How can I fix this?

Comment: What does it smell like? Mold? Like something died?

Comment: @George If I understand the question correctly then the smell occurs only when the A/C is off.

Comment: Smells like someone peed into the vents! And when the A/C is NOT on.